# Meaning of the number sent with Netconf payload

Tags: ssh, rfc, netconf

I am using confd based Netconf agent. When I checked the XML payload received by the agent, I see a number prefixed in the payload. It is not message-id. What is this prefix? Please give any RFC reference which explains the prefix.

For example, "#164" is prefixed with the get-config payload.

```
#164
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<rpc message-id=\"0\"
    xmlns=\"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0\">
    <get-config>
        <source>
            <running/>
        </source>
    </get-config>
</rpc>
```

Similarly, different prefixes are used for the other Netconf operation as listed below.

```
get 118
close-session 128
lock 154
unlock 158
delete-config 172
edit-config 190
copy-config 193
```

Comment: Does this number vary with the length of the payload, or is it a fixed integer depending on the operation?

Answer (score 1):

NETCONF over SSH uses a special form of [chunked framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6242#section-4.2) for the exchanged XML stanzas. Essentially, it's a way for the parser at the other side to see when an individual message ends.

Answer (score 1):

The `#164` you are seeing is a part of NETCONF 1.1 over SSH chunked framing mechanism.

[RFC6242, Section 4.2, Chunked Framing Mechanism](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6242#section-4.2)

> As an example, the message:
>
> ```
>   <rpc message-id="102"
>        xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
>     <close-session/>
>   </rpc>
> ```
>
> could be encoded as (using '\n' as a visible representation of the
> LineFeed character):
>
> ```
> C:  \n#4\n
> C:  <rpc
> C:  \n#18\n
> C:   message-id="102"\n
> C:  \n#79\n
> C:       xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">\n
> C:    <close-session/>\n
> C:  </rpc>
> C:  \n##\n
> ```

The length of bytes in your example matches if you strip away all formatting chars:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rpc message-id="0" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"><get-config><source><running/></source></get-config></rpc>
```